# javascript promise catch in then

Tags: javascript, try-catch, es6-promise

I have an abstraction using knex promises:
**Core.js**

```
class CoreModel {
  constructor(tableName) {
  this.table = tableName;
}

add(payload, table) {
  return this.conn()(table ? table : this.table)
    .insert(payload)
    .then(id => id)
    .catch(err => getMsg(300, err))
    .finally(() => { this.conn().destroy() });
}
```

I am calling in a controller:

**register.js**

```
return this.Users.add(request.payload.users)
  .then(id => id)
  .catch(err => err);
```

why is it that in the `core.js` it does go to the catch as intended but the catch does not propagate to the `catch` but to the `then` in `register.js` am I completely missing something with promises errors?

Really scratching my head here, it's simple but can't figure it out.

Thanks in advance :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're catching it in (add), and catching works just like it does in normal functions -- if you catch it, it disappears.

```
function add(a, b) {
    try {
        return a+b;
    } catch(e) {
      return something;
    }
}
```

when you call 'add' within a try catch block. you'll never catch anything

If you want the error to keep going, do something like this

```
.catch(err => {getMsg(300, err); throw err;})
```

Comment: Oh snap, I did not know that! Thanks buddy you helped a 2 hour issue in a minute! :D awesome ty

Comment: by the way, alternative is `.catch(err => Promise.reject(getMsg(300, err)))`

Comment: that makes sense but I actually prefer syntax wise the throw "it's cleaner". But I guess it could be based on what we want to do. in this case I just wanted a direct line with the abstract promise. Thanks btw :D always good to have alternatives hihi